# iFrame marin-bottom not working

Tags: iframe, margin

I'm using negative margin settings on the IFrame to show only the specific section of the source.

I have the code like this to cut off some of the top, left and bottom section of the Iframe source. While the top and left sections of the source are trimmed nicely, "margin-bottom" setting doesn't cut-off the bottom section of the source page.

any clues on what is going wrong here and suggestions to fix it? Thanks

```html
<div dir="ltr" style="width: 100%; height: 800px; overflow: hidden; display: block;">

<p dir="ltr">
   <iframe height="800" scrolling="yes" src="http://localhost/testPage.html" 
     style="overflow: hidden; margin-top: -180px; margin-bottom: -180px; margin-left: -260px;" 
     width="100%">
    </iframe>
 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Share the code please.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div dir="ltr" style="width: 100%; height: 800px; overflow: hidden; display: block;">

<p dir="ltr">
   <iframe height="800" scrolling="yes" src="http://localhost/testPage.html" 
     style="overflow: hidden; margin-top: -180px; margin-bottom: -180px; margin-left: -260px;" 
     width="100%">
    </iframe>
 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry. I didn't follow what is the solution here.